# DELETE FROM statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, rows

I have a table in a database called 'threads' and I want to delete a row where the id is equal to $forumid which is set by the URL. The URL looks something like this: domain.com/viewThread.php?forumid=1
I am getting this using

```
 $forumid = $_GET['forumid'];
```

and I am sure that this is working because I use

```
echo $forumid;
```

and it works correctly. But when I go to delete a row using

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM threads WHERE id='$forumid'");
```

its not working for some reason.
Can somebody please help me with this? Is it possible that there is something wrong with my phpMyAdmin or mySQL database?

Comment: echo your delete query and check whats wrong in this?

Comment: `"DELETE FROM \`threads\` WHERE \`id\` = $forumid"`

Comment: Please add more code. Use prepared statements. Do you get any error message?

Comment: Is there any database error thrown?. please share database error.

Comment: @RakeshSingh There is no error reported... I don't know what is going on. I'm not sure if its my code or my database...

Comment: try $db->query("DELETE FROM threads WHERE id={$forumid}"); if it still not working then print your sql and execute sql directly in database and see is there any error in query.

Comment: What happens, if I send the following value as `forumid`: `'; DROP TABLE threads; SELECT '` (Keywords for your next web searches: `sql injection` `prepared statements`). Are you in the database where the `thread` table exists? Is it possible, that the record with the given ID does not exist (there is no row to delete)? Does the user, you are using to connect to the database have the `DELETE` privilege on the `threads` table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WHERE clause effecting SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362649/where-clause-effecting-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM threads WHERE id='.$forumid.'");
```

Comment: no these aren't working. but where do you think that i could check for errors thrown in phpmyadmin? because I turned error reporting on and its giving me nothing.

Comment: check  $forumid = $_GET['forumid']; are you getting this id properly

Comment: i even changed to query to DELETE FROM threads WHERE id=1 and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Check the query

```
("DELETE FROM threads WHERE id= '.$forumid.'");
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try by using any of the below codes.

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM threads WHERE id='.$forumid.'");
```

OR

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM threads WHERE id=$forumid");
```